# Instantiate 3D models from an external folder

Tags: unity-game-engine, external, assets

I have small project that I am creating to learn a bit more about Unity.

In this project I have a lot of 3D models, and I need to use only some of them. I am using external text file that the program reads when executed, in order to tell it which models to load.

For example, in the text file I can write:
Hunter, CandyHouse

and the program would instantiate those 2 models only.

My problem is that I don't want to save all the models in the Resources folder and load onluly those I need, because that would increase my program size drastically. So what I want to do is to save the models I need next to the text file and instantiate them. But I don't know how to access them from Unity.

I have found the WWW class in some answer, but they used it to load textures, when I tried to load Maya file with it, Unity just stopped responding.

Is there anyway to do it¿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use model make a prefab.(This can decrease draw call when you need many model in scene.)
- Use this prefab make a assetbundle.
- put this assetbundle in your url(this could be a remote server url or a file url.Note that iOS/Android may have problem on permission of read/write).
- And use the code follows to load.

  ```
  WWW www = new WWW("url");    
  yield return www;

  GameObject obj = Object.Instantiate(www.assetBundle.Load("ModelName")) as GameObject;
  ```

We could also use [LoadFromCacheOrDownload](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload.html),the asset will be save speficy location.So no need everytime load from web.

Comment: @user9977758 your url could a remote server url.I hope this can help you.

Comment: I have created a prefab, but how do I make AssetBundle¿

Comment: I have just one question, where is the 3D model is saved¿ the asset bundle size is 1.7 mb and the model is 19 mb, so can you write me where is the model¿

Comment: @user9977758 assetbundle is compressed data so it small. It first load in memory from web and you could save your model in Application.persistentDataPath. So no need everytime load from web.

Comment: @user9977758 you could also use WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload, this will cache in speficy location.